# How would I remove content from a page when hovering over an image. Each piece of content has its own id

Tags: javascript

[problem child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyRvV.png) [working child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRK71.png)I have 4 different images on my html page. when I hover over each image a text box appears. The problem is that one of the boxes displays content that goes over an image with 100% opacity making the text impossible to read. My solution is to write some JS that says

if I hover over image 2 make image 3 & 4 opacity become 0

I'm not an experenced coder so i'm sure a simple solution will resolve my matter.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by "text box"?

Answer (score 0):

Add this class to your css file

```
.hide {
  opacity: 0!important;
}
```

Add id selectors to your html img tags

```
<img src="/..." id="imageOneID"/>
<img src="/..." id="imageTwoID"/>
<img src="/..." id="imageThreeID"/>
<img src="/..." id="imageFourID"/>
```

And this would be the javascript

```
// create an array of your images
const images = [
  document.getElementById('imageOneID'),
  document.getElementById('imageTwoID'),
  document.getElementById('imageThreeID'),
  document.getElementById('imageFourID')
];

// show the hovered image and hide others
images.forEach((singleImage,index) => {
  singleImage.addEventListener('mouseover', ()=>{
    singleImage.classList.remove('hide');
    images.forEach((_singleImage, _index) => {
      if (_index !== index) {
        _singleImage.classList.add('hide');
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Hello Thank you so much for commenting. I have a problem. when I add the css 

.hide-and-show {
    opacity: 0!important;
  }

Then I add the class hide-and-show to each of the 4 images divs the images disapear from the display. Now I can click on the images and drag them. Its almost like they are all still their just with a 0 opacity now.

Comment: Marcus,I am trying to understand your problem; First of all, you shouldn't add hide class to your images, javascript will add it and remove it on hover event. If "opacity: 0" is not helping, replace "opacity:0" with "display: none" or "transform:translateY(-100vh)"

Comment: By the way i changed the name of the class as hide (it was hide-and-show)

Comment: Hello Ci Boz, I've updated my question with a couple pictures. I think it'll help clear up what my problem is.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like you need to give css z-index higher to the gray text box. Because on the problem image you shared, gray text box seems like staying under other icon overlays. If gray text box has `position: absolute` or `position:relative`  you should add a higher z-index than other components. For example try this `z-index: 99999999999999999` on gray text box. If gray text box component doesn't have position yet. Add `position:relative` and after add `z-index: 99999999999999999`. This way gray component will come over the others.

Comment: Hello Boz, so the objects on each side are in the same divs, so I can move one up and one down with z-index. Is their a method to make my z-index alternate which one is 2 depending on the mouse hover?